# How to display the data in html table on selecting particular option in dropdown using jinja2 and python flask

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I have one admin and one dropdown which contains 10 user details(like userid and username) initially, I am displaying table data with admin id and I want to display the data by userid which I will select from dropdown.

I am displaying the table data using jinja2 Templating

My Html Page.

```html
{% for info in data %}
<tr class="item">
   <td>{{ info. userid}}</td>
   <td>{{ info.username}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

My routes.

```py
@api.route("/userinfo")
def Info():
   data = information(1)
   return render_template("users.html", data=data)
```

Comment: What's your question? Where's your data coming from?

Comment: You need to call the `userinfo` service once you select an item from the dropdown.